# 3DES (DESede)- Decrypt encrypted text (done by JAVA) in C#

Tags: java, c#, encryption

The encrypted text is done in JAVA (which we have no JAVA background at all)

The decryption will be in C#, and here is the code

```
public static string DecryptString(string Message, string Passphrase)
{
    byte[] Results;
    UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();

    MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase));
    // byte[] TDESKey = UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase);
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
    // TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CTS;
    TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    byte[] DataToDecrypt =  Convert.FromBase64String(Message);

    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
        Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
        HashProvider.Clear();
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Results);
}
```

Encrypted Java code is

```
public  String encryptData(String privateKey, String rawData)  
{

    Cipher cipher = null;
    try 
    {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(privateKey));
        byte[] plainText = rawData.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedText));
    } 
}
```

However, when tried to decrypt, got the error message: BAD DATA

Where am I missing here?

Comment: AFAIK, `DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME` returns a 3DES instance in `ECB` mode, whereas .NET's `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()` defaults to `CBC` mode. Set `TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB`

Comment: How exactly is `DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME` defined? Other issues: a) Oracle JCE provider doesn't support `PaddingMode.Zeros`. You would have to use BouncyCastle. b) You're not doing any MD5 key derivation in Java. Besides, don't derive a key through a single MD5 invocation. If you have passwords, then you need to use a proper scheme such as PBKDF2 or Argon2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using MD5 in Java, so you should not be using it in your .NET for computing the hash.

Your key should have been generated using a specific encoding and same you should use in .NET.

Please note, there is some fundamental difference in java `KeySpec` and the Key being used for `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider`.  As mentioned by Microsfot https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Triple DES only supports ***"key lengths from 128 bits to 192 bits in increments of 64 bits"***

So you need to convert your key appropriately before assigning. To do this you can use the Array.Resize method as following.

```
byte[] TDESKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase);
System.Array.Resize(ref TDESKey , 192 / 8);
```

Hope this will help.